# set video position start to finish when scroll start and finish the video container using jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, video, scroll

I want to fix the video when scroll, if the video container scrolled the video want to start but not to play. the position of the video want to vary. it want to slice from start to finish the container with offset.

Comment: Can you be more specific with your issue. Fiddle will be more useful.

Comment: this is the video url http://vreasolutions.com/demo/fell/wp-content/themes/fell-theme/video/video.mp4 , http://vreasolutions.com/demo/fell/ initially video ll be pause mode. when we scroll the video container the video current time want to start the video wen completeing the video container the video current time is equal to video time